# Entity framework. Counting database hits

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When working with NHibernate I was able to count, in a test, how many times I hit the database which was great (guards from unintentional mistakes when rewriting queries).

Is it possible count/detect when a query is executed when using the Enitity Framerwork?

An example test would look like this:

```
int currentSqlCounter = EntityFrameWork.QueryCount();
MyMethodBeingTested();
Assert.AreEqual( 2, EntityFrameWork.QueryCount() - currentSqlCounter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for logging in EntityFramework is quite weak and I don't know of any in-the-box solution for this.

I used the Tracing capabilities of the  EFProviderWrappers  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers to do something similar in a previous project.